# Flutter GestureDetector misses onTap when another TextField has focus

Tags: flutter

Hi in Flutter I have a `TextFormField` and separately a `GestureDetector`.  The problem is when the TextFormField has focus (user is typing) and then user clicks on GestureDetector the `onTap` is not called so the user has to click twice once to remove focus from the TextFormField and again to activate the GestureDetector, which is irritatating for the user.  Any tips please to detect a tap even if a TextFormField has focus? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I Think you can add

```
FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
```

to remove focus from textfield at 'onEditingComplete' or 'onTap'.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Is your GestureDetector only to lose focus? if so try wrap your scaffold with Gesture Detector and add onTap like code below

```
      onTap: () {
FocusScopeNode currentFocus = FocusScope.of(context);
if (!currentFocus.hasPrimaryFocus) {
  currentFocus.unfocus();
}
```

}

It will unfocus the TextFormField once you tap anywhere in scaffold

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone!  This was actually my mistake, there was a listener in the TextFormField that was triggering a setState and drowning the ontap.